# regex and upper and lower case

Tags: php, regex, case-insensitive

i'm using this

```
preg_match('/<meta\s+http-equiv="Content-Type" content="([^;]+)(?:;\s*charset=["]?([^"^\s]*))?"/i', $html, $match)
```

to get the **charset** but this will not work with this

```
<META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1256">
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have double quotes in [preg_match()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) but not in html example.

Here: **http-equiv=Content-Type**

If You want to support preg_match() to work with and without quotes here, simple change code to this:

```
preg_match('/<meta\s+http-equiv=(")?Content-Type(")?\s+content="([^;]+)(?:;\s*charset=["]?([^"^\s]*))?"/i', $html, $match);
```

Better version that will work when attributes order change:

```
preg_match('/<meta.+?content="([^;]+)(?:;\s*charset=["]?([^"^\s]*))?"/i', $html, $match);
```

Comment: Current preg_match() will work with both because of "i" flag.

Comment: It works OK for me, but You should use better version that will work also when attributes order change: preg_match('/<meta.+?content="([^;]+)(?:;\s*charset=["]?([^"^\s]*))?"/i', $html, $match);

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in getting the charset, why not using something simpler like:

```
preg_match('/charset=([^"]+)/i', $html, $match);
```

Of course, you can tweak it to meet your specific needs, but keep it simple and it'll be much easier to get it to work.